# How can recipients view all signatures

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign's SOAP api v3.0.

I want recipients to be able to view all recipient signatures in a contract. Right now, recipients are only able to see their own signature.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `Group Signatures`?

Comment: Recipients will see all the E-signatures which are done before him on the envelope. If its not happening in this way, then you need to edit the qs, and share the code and workflow which you are doing.

Comment: edit the qs? what is the qs? essentially, I create an envelope, supply it with documents, add all recipients and create envelope and send. Not sure why it's not showing all current signatures? @AmitKBist

Comment: edit your post with the code and workflow which you are using, as you are seeing the signing behavior diff from what we have seen

Comment: would posting the params of createandsendenvelope be enough?

Comment: add exact XML after masking the name and email of the actual signer, also you can remove the document bytes

Comment: You mean the response xml after they had signed? @AmitKBist

Comment: Your request XML

Answer (score 0):

When you send an envelope with DocuSign, any recipient can see anything that was done before they viewed the document. So that if you use routing order, for example, recipient 2 can view the signatures of recipient 1. Recipient 1 would be able to go back to the document and view recipient 2 signatures once the envelope is complete and they get an email to that effect.
Hope that helps.